# how to compare multiple json file to a defined structure json file if josn file has multiple occurrences of list section

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a structure json file which looks like this :

```
{
   "School" : 
  {
    "Teachers" : [ 
        {
            "Subject" : { },
            "Experience" : { },
            "Date of Birth" : { }
        } 
    ],
    "Class_Rooms" : { },
    "Playgrounds" : { },
    "Staff" : [ 
        {
            "Year-2021" : { },
            "Year-2022" : { }
        }
    ]
  }
```

}

It's a fixed structure and I have to compare this multiple json files to this defined structure and create an excel summary report which shows that `Expected` , `Actual` and `Result`.
I wrote the following code :

```
import json
import os
import pandas as pd

json_folder = "Path"
structure_folder = "Path"

with open(os.path.join(structure_folder, "structure.json"), "r") as f:
    json_structure = json.load(f)

def get_all_keys(d, curr_key=[]):
for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        yield from get_all_keys(v, curr_key + [k])
    elif isinstance(v, list):
        for i in v:
            yield from get_all_keys(i, curr_key + [k])
    else:
        yield '.'.join(curr_key + [k])


struct_keys = [*get_all_keys(json_structure)]
structure_keys = set(struct_keys)


json_files = os.listdir(json_folder)

Summary_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Json filename', 'Status'])

for file in json_files :
  with open(os.path.join(json_folder, file), "r") as x:
    data = json.load(x)
    file_keys = [*get_all_keys(data)]
    #file_keys.sort()
    json_file_keys = set(file_keys)

    removed_keys = structure_keys.difference(json_file_keys)
    added_keys = json_file_keys.difference(structure_keys)
    
    
    if removed_keys == set() and added_keys == set():
        Summary_df = Summary_df._append({'Json filename' : file, 'Status' : 'Pass'}, ignore_index = True)

    elif removed_keys != set() and added_keys != set():
        Summary_df = Summary_df._append({'Json filename' : file, 'Status' : 'Fail'}, ignore_index = True)

        all_values = set(struct_keys + file_keys)
        
        rows = []
        for value in all_values:
            row_dict = {'Expected Value': value if value in struct_keys else None,
                        'Actual Value': value if value in file_keys else None}
            if row_dict['Expected Value'] is None or row_dict['Actual Value'] is None:
                row_dict['Result'] = "Fail"
            else:
                row_dict['Result'] = "Pass"
            rows.append(row_dict)
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
        df.to_excel(file + '.xlsx', index=False)
  


with pd.ExcelWriter('Summary_report.xlsx') as writer:
    Summary_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary', index=False)
```

What it does is it will extract the `structure` in `struct_key` variable and extracting the json file keys in `file_keys` and comparing them by keys. If keys don't much it will create none row's in an excel rows and populate the `result` column with `pass` and `fail`.

The problem here is in above example `Teachers` section is `list` and it can have multiple occurrences in a json file like below :

```
{
"School" : 
{
    "Teachers" : [ 
        {
            "Subject" : { },
            "Experience" : { },
            "Date of Birth" : { }
        }, 
        {
            "Subject" : { },
            "Experience" : { },
            "Date of Birth" : { }
        }, 
        {
            "Subject" : { },
            "Experience" : { },
            "Date of Birth" : { }
        } 
    ],
    "Class_Rooms" : { },
    "Playgrounds" : { },
    "Staff" : [ 
        {
            "Year-2021" : { },
            "Year-2022" : { }
        }
    ]
 }
```

}

and the output that I am trying to achieve here is in spite of multiple occurrences the `result` column in the excel should be populated as `pass` because the key's are same and if `subject` is changed to `suject` for 1 occurrence then it should be populated as `Fail` only that specific row item.

Please help me out or suggest me a way to solve this.

Edit 1 : Added Path
Edit 2 : Updated the question

Comment: Have you checked out https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Hi @JonSG yes I did it will validate the file but i am not sure how will i create the expected output fill because `.validate` function will return `true` or `false`

Comment: So long story short, you have jsonschema validation, but you want more info on why a file fails the validation? The above link has a whole section on "Handling Validation Errors." But if you don't want to use the library and want to write your own code, give me a minute to reread the question. I don't really see the difference between the first and last json on first glance.

Comment: So, testing your code, I don't get any response from get_all_keys. Maybe you should delete everything from the question except the get_all_keys function, a description of what it should do, and of course the data it's supposed to be parsing. I think the problem that it has no base case for an empty dict, thus you to never actually reach a yield.

Comment: Also avoid using a mutable as a default value. It doesn't get changed in this code, which would change the default in unrelated future calls to the function, but that is a danger.

Comment: Hi @KennyOstrom , Thanks for the response. I really apologize for not able to create a perfect example but the JSON file that i am using it has deep nested key : value pair, i wish i could have shared that
get_all_keys function is working fine ( i am able to extract all the keys ) it might not be working with the current example because of limited number of pair i put there. 
The intention here is the for loop ` for values in all_values` i need help there so that even if the 2nd json file have multiple occurrences of `teachers` as explained in the 2nd example it should generate the output

Comment: and in the excel file the 1 : 1 comparison is viewable, 
there is a specific output request that's why i am building my own code otherwise jsonschema is best suited here. 
And yes there is a difference in both the json example because in iteration is written once in the structure but in 2nd json it's repeated thrice based on the actual data. 
output should be clean enough to display why this specific key pair is marked as `fail`.

Comment: This is a pass/fail function. Each row represents whether an entire file passed or failed validation. Are you wanting line numbers from the original json? You used json.loads, you don't know what the line numbers are for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're analyzing the python data structures, we can't give json metadata like line numbers. But you can add the list index to the string.

I still think you should look into jsonschema, but here's how I can modify your code to include a list enumeration in the text string you're currently using to identify nodes:

First, I fixed get_all_keys, which wasn't working at all. Then I added an enumeration so now the keys look like "School.Teaches[0].Experience" and I use a function to strip those indexes to compare to the expected json_structure.

I dropped all the pandas and excel stuff. You can handle that separately.

Oh yeah, you'll also notice I modified the test data to actually have schema errors. That's a pretty important step. The first teacher is set up correctly. The next two have some key modified.

```
json_structure = {
   "School":
    {
        "Teachers": [
            {
                "Subject": {},
                "Experience": {},
                "Date of Birth": {}
            }
        ],
        "Class_Rooms": {},
        "Playgrounds": {},
        "Staff": [
            {
                "Year-2021": {},
                "Year-2022": {}
            }
        ]
    }
}

data = {
    "School":
    {
        "Teachers": [
            {
                "Subject": {},
                "Experience": {},
                "Date of Birth": {}
            },
            {
                "Area of Expertise": {},
                "Experience": {},
                "Date of Birth": {}
            },
            {
                "Subject": {},
                "Years Teaching": {},
                "Date of Birth": {}
            }
        ],
        "Class_Rooms": {},
        "Playgrounds": {},
        "Staff": [
            {
                "Year-2021": {},
                "Year-2022": {}
            }
        ]
    }
}


def get_all_keys(data, curr_key=None, include_index=False):
    if curr_key == None:
        curr_key = []
    if data:
        for key, value in data.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                yield from get_all_keys(value, curr_key + [str(key)], include_index=include_index)
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                for index, item in enumerate(value):
                    new_key = str(key) + f'[{index}]' if include_index else key
                    yield from get_all_keys(item, curr_key + [new_key], include_index=include_index)
            else:
                yield '.'.join((curr_key, str(key)))
    else:
        if curr_key:
            yield '.'.join(curr_key)


def strip_indexes(message):
    def helper(message, skip=False):
        for character in message:
            if character == '[':
                skip = True
            if not skip:
                yield character            
            if character == ']':
                skip = False
    return ''.join(helper(message))

if 'School.Teachers.Subject' != strip_indexes('School.Teachers[5].Subject'):
    raise ValueError('test failed')


struct_keys = [*get_all_keys(json_structure)]
structure_keys = set(struct_keys)

def check_data(data, structure_keys):
    json_file_keys = set()
    for key in get_all_keys(data, include_index=True):
        scheme_key = strip_indexes(key)
        json_file_keys.add(scheme_key)
        if scheme_key not in structure_keys:
            yield f'unknown key "{key}"'

    removed_keys = structure_keys.difference(json_file_keys)
    for key in removed_keys:
        yield f'missing key "{key}"'


for message in check_data(data, structure_keys):
    print(message)
```

> unknown key "School.Teachers[1].Area of Expertise"
> unknown key "School.Teachers[2].Years Teaching"

You'll notice that it does not report a missing key for what those should have been, because you used a set. One of the teachers is set up correctly, and you've removed duplicates (by relying on set operations), so you can't test for those missing keys unless they're all missing.